# Wrong number of arguments when instantiating an object

Tags: ruby, object, instantiation

I am instantiating an object from within another object and I am getting a "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) error.

Here is my initialize function (nothing really in it)

```
class Handler::AtReply
    def initialize(stream, logger)
      # Actual operation for this handler goes here
    end
end
```

Where I am calling it:

```
def load_handlers
  @logger.log("Loading Handlers")
  StatusBot::Handler.constants.sort.each do |handler_name|
    puts handler_name
    @logger.log("Loading Handler: #{handler_name}")
handler = StatusBot::Handler.const_get(handler_name).new(@stream, @logger)
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong when it comes to instantiating the object, and what do I need to do fo make it work?

Comment: Could you please give here the full definition of the class and error trace also?

Comment: Does every handler class take two parameters in it's initializer?

Comment: Yes, all handlers have two parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why it fixed it, but I changed from each handler having its own initialize to having one that is inherited from the Handler "parent" class, and then using a separate "load" method to do what I was originally trying to do.